# video event listener not firing on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

Simply trying to redirect after video finishes, works great on all browsers except mobile chrome and safari. Doesn't seem to catch the event, what am I missing?

```
function playVideo(){

var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    window.location = 'appt.html';
});
 
}
```

```
<video controls id="video"  width="100%" onclick="playVideo()">
<source src="./advisors/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inline javascript onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567749/inline-javascript-onclick-event)

Comment: No, unless I am just to obtuse to understand it, lol.

Comment: You have unclosed `</video>` tag. It is not related to this question but it is **invalid**. You can't listen `ended` event inside click function. Use external function for listen `ended` event like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes) (see answers) and make it listen once DOM loaded. You don't have to remove `controls` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the fix was to simply remove the "controls" attribute from "video" element.

Answer (score 0):

Because your onclick function does not firing on touch devices

```js
function playVideo() {

  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    window.location = 'appt.html';
  });

}
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener("canplay", playVideo)
```

```html
<video controls id="video" width="100%">
<source src="./advisors/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: This JS will make video auto play. To make  `ended` independent, move listen `ended` to outside or do the same like `canplay`.

Comment: @vee ofc. Here i'm showing that the problem is the absence of click events on touch screens. I wrongly assumed that it's obvious that video.play() will run when "video can play"